# Get objectname (as seen from Qt Designer) from QWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qtgui, qobject

I want to disable all but a selected set of widgets in my Qt application.

What I am trying to do is to iterate all children of mainWindow using `findChildren` and disable all the resulting widgets except 'myTable' using `setEnabled(false)`.

```
QList<QWidget *> allWidgets = mainWindow->findChildren<QWidget *>("");
QList<QWidget*>::iterator it;
for (it = allWidgets.begin(); it != allWidgets.end(); it++) {
    if ((*it)->objectName() != "myTable")  // here, objectName is not working!!
    {
        (*it)->setEnabled(false);
    } 
}
```

`objectName()` inside the above `if` statement is not working. What do I put there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `accessibleName` property. Set it for the widget you need, and then check it in your cycle with `acessibleName()` function. It is an empty string by default, so it should be fairly easy to find your widget.

Another alternative is to disable all widgets, and then just enable the one you need directly:

```
for( QWidget * w : widgets )
{
    w->setEnabled(false);
}

ui->myTable->setEnabled(true);
```

Or, finally, you can set the `objectName` property with the `setObjectName()` function, and use it as you do in your code.

Comment: Thank you. I actually went about disabling all widgets and enabling the one I want.

Comment: Please use foreach in a Qt code rather than C++11 only features. That is why foreach is still kept around because Qt has to work with pre-c++11 compilers at this point of time.

Comment: @lpapp I hugely doubt C++ keeps `foreach` around just for the sake of one 3rd-party library. Users can program in whichever dialect of C++ they want; they aren't mandated to support pre-11 compilers. Besides, even in 2012, before you posted, Qt was using C++11 features _within itself_: http://woboq.com/blog/cpp11-in-qt5.html. I suggest you stop reeling off your own coding opinions as if they were facts everyone else has to obey.

Answer (score 6):

The `objectName` function does not return the class name or the variable name, but the actual object name **you** have set with [`QObject::setObjectName`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#objectName-prop). Therefore you first need to set it in your table with:

```
myTable->setObjectName("myTable");
```

Comment: As **SingerOfTheFall** suggested, disabling all widgets and enabling the one I want was easier in my case. But thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Write this on the first row (remove the quotation marks from the brackets):

```
QList<QWidget *> allWidgets = mainWindow->findChildren<QWidget *>();
```